# Android Studio - git Local Changes file list - why is ignore option not clickable?

Tags: git, android-studio, gitignore

How is it that sometimes I can right click and ignore files but sometimes not?

image showing no possibility to perform ignore on the selected file:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio is just following git rules. `gitignore` is for files which are not tracked yet (didn't added to git) , and here you're trying to ignore already tracked file.
In order to stop tracking you should use `git rm --cached`, See official  [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_notes).
I'm not sure if that's possible using Android Studio git UI.